# Pattern to synchronize backend, Javascript and DOM state

Tags: javascript, dom, design-patterns

Being relatively new to the web world, I encountered a (pretty common?) problem.

Developping a multiplayer game, I'm having trouble handling disconnections. Server and clients communicate through websockets, so whenever a client is disconnected, he misses on the notifications sent by the other clients (routed by the server). Which means that :

- whenever a client is disconnected, I need to record all changes happening afterwards.
- when he connects back, I need to send him all this info
- the client then needs to be able to replay these records to sync with the server state.

I was wondering if there was some kind of design pattern to handle this problem (rather than an implementation specific solution).  I believe it's kind of what React, Vue etc... are meant for (?), but I'd rather avoid using any heavy framework.

Any ressource/doc would also be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

- [Transaction](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs614/2002sp/Transactions.pdf) in Distributed Systems is a related technique (but it is not categorized as a design pattern.)
- [Memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) provides the ability to restore an object to its previous state, so it's also somehow related.
- The approach you described in the question seems to be good. Maybe you don't need a pattern to fit in.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) there's definitely some stuff in the transaction course I could try to apply